# How can $n^5+4$ be a perfect square?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

How can one find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $n^5+4$ is a perfect square?

I see that $n^5=(x+2)(x-2)$ here im suck can someone help ?

Comment: what are the possible values of $\gcd(x+2, x-2)?$ When $ab = n^5$ and $\gcd(a,b)$ is an explicit (very small) number, what can you  say about $a,b?$ For a start, what if  $\gcd(a,b)=1?$

Comment: I really didn't understand :(

Comment: We can say that they are primer between them right ?

Comment: There is at least an example: $2^5+4=6^2$. (I was trying to prove that there were no solutions until I found that).

Comment: What are you doing in class now? What is your background in mathematics, as relates to this sort of problem?

Comment: OP may have taken it from [AoPS](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u244835h1082433p4764356).

Comment: @will jagy im in my two years before university

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution:

$d=\gcd(x+2,x-2)$ is $1$, $2$ or $4$.

If $d=1$ then $x+2$ and $x-2$ are perfect fifth powers. That is clearly impossible.

If $d=2$ then $x+2=2a$ and $x-2=2^4b=16b$ where $a$ is odd and $b$ is an integer (or vice versa). Either way, we have that $x=a+8b$, which is odd; a contradiction.

If $d=4$ then $x+2=4a$ and $x-2=4a-4$, where $a$ is some integer, that is, $x=4a-2$. Then $n$ is even, that is, $n=2m$ and
$$2m^5=a^2-a$$

There is at least one example, for $a=2$.

Comment: in the middle case, add in $x+2 = 16 b$ and $x-2 = 2a$ as a (potentially separate) case. In the final case, similar split, as $\gcd(a,a-1) = 1,$ both are fifth powers times powers of $2$ that are completely predictable.

Comment: Indeed, one of $a,a-1$ is odd and the other even, just two cases.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not sure I see how to finish that argument. If $a=2b$ we get $m^5=b(2b-1)$, so $b$ and $2b-1$ must both be 5th powers. This seems unlikely for $b>1$, but why?

Comment: @AlonAmit, if I think of something I will let you know.  I felt involved for a little while, then lost interest when it turned out this was yet another problem from aops, no genuine source known, no context that might point to methods guaranteed to work.

Comment: It's funny: I stumbled upon this problem elsewhere, and refused to work on it for precisely these reasons - until I came here and saw you mention that it's straightforward!